# Using custom colors in Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create custom hex colors for my React/TypeScript app using Tailwind.

Why doesn't the background color change with the color variable value?

Here is my code:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

    const ColorChanger = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState('#ffffff');

      const handleColorChange = () => {
        const randomColor = `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`;
        console.log("setColor = ", randomColor)
        setColor(randomColor);
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <div className={`w-20 h-20 bg-[${color}] mx-auto mb-4`}>{color}</div>

          <button
            type="button"
            className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
            onClick={handleColorChange}
          >
            Changer la couleur
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ColorChanger />
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Index.css

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    code {
      font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
      monospace;
    }

    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
```

App.css

```
...
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
```

How can I use custom colors with Tailwind CSS?

Comment: Read about [dynamic class names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) in Tailwind here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're having trouble with using dynamic colors in your Tailwind CSS classes.
Tailwind CSS doesn't usually support dynamic variables in class names, which might be causing your issue with the background color not changing.

One simple way to fix this is to use inline styles with React. You can set the backgroundColor directly on your div like this.

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: color}} className="w-20 h-20 mx-auto mb-4">{color}</div>
```

This way, your color state will be applied directly to the div's backgroundColor, while still keeping your other Tailwind styles intact.